# Running init first in NodeUnit - separate file

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, webstorm, nodeunit

Currently I am developing nodeunit tests and I stumbled upon a problem.

I have a folder named "Unit_tests"

In this folder I have a file "testInitializer.js" which contains 2 methods:
**init** and **term**.

These methods should be run just once and only at the beginning and the end of all the other tests. Other tests are in separate folders under the root "Unit_tests".

How can I make sure this file is run **first**.

As of now, it does mostly but in some cases it doesn't.
Is there a way in `webstorm` to make sure it runs first?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using this?: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-nodeunit

Comment: I use https://github.com/caolan/nodeunit - got it through `npm install nodeunit`

Comment: Yes, additionally to nodeunit, you can use the grunt plugin I mentioned to define tasks in such a way that "testInitializer.js" would be run before and after your tests.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without the grunt plugin?

Comment: I don't know. I haven't worked with NodeUnit yet, so my suggestion is kind of a shot in the dark. Having said that, I personally would create  grunt commands as external tools in Webstorm and write grunt tasks with aforementioned plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, this is not possible with only NodeUnit, since it uses an asynchronous approach where the callbacks don't execute in a predictable order. This behavior is by desing, and is supposed to provide a more realistic testing routines and prevent dependencies between tests.

You can however use [Grunt JS](http://gruntjs.com/) with the [NodeUnit plugin](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-nodeunit) to take full control of your testing process.

You can find a great article on this topic here:
http://markdalgleish.com/2012/09/test-driven-node-js-development-with-grunt/

Comment: Okay, I guess I'll have to settle with this answer. Too bad though. Thanks!